# Removing superuser privileges in Hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, privileges

I have installed Hadoop under Ubuntu using WSL in Windows 10, using the [linked instructions](https://kontext.tech/column/hadoop/307/install-hadoop-320-on-windows-10-using-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl).
To my surprise, I can put files into the root (`/`) folder in HDFS without sudo. How do I change this, so that writing to directories above my user directory (`/user/<user_name>`) would require sudo?

Comment: You can't unless you kerberize/secure the cluster. Without proper authentication, any hadoop user can execute `$ export HADOOP_USER_NAME=<super-somebody>`, and become that somebody.

Comment: @mazaneicha I am not looking for bullet-proof protection, only that one should not mess up files outside of his user space by mistake.